# Importing large product categories into wordpress menu

Tags: menus, woocommerce-offtopic, sub-menu

I have imported a product dataset into Wordpress/WooComerce which has created the required categories and sub-categories correctly when viewed in the Product->Categories page.

When I go to try to create the menus from Product Category structure only a small amount of the subcategories are indenting. The first image show the indenting as it should be, the second image shows where it stops. It looks like it is not listing them in the correct order which may be throwing the sub-category structure which goes 3 levels deep.

There are just over 240 categories so I am not sure if this would cause an issue.

Is there any other way to import a large number of categories into a menu and maintain the structure.

[image: This shows the correct indent]

[image: This shows where the indenting stops working]

Comment: Menus tend to break when you have too many items in them. I would instead use `wp_list_categories` (you'll need to use 'taxonomy' and set it to whatever name WC uses for Product Categories) in the theme. That way they're always up to date without anyone touching a Menu.

Comment: Thanks. I have not used WP at this level before but will look into it and report back to the post.

Comment: i am facing the same issue in WP customization page

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not import all categories into menu.
maybe it will not be useful to load into every single page.
main categories into menu, then add sub categories into side panel.
what do you think ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/261999)